# Compile several XSD's containing duplicate definitions of the same element with JAXB

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

**Question:** 
How do i make xjc/Jaxb generate the propper javaclasses for several schemas containing duplicate elementdefinitions in the same namespace?

**Information:**
I have three .xsd schemas: A,B and C. All have the same targetnamespace.
They are all 3 shemas that has been given to me, and i am not, in any way possible, allowed to change them in any way.

They A has some elements that is also found in B or C (but A has a lot of self declared elements as well)
Example: This is the same "code" for A and C:

```
<xs:simpleType name="y_ym_ymdDatoType">
    <xs:union memberTypes="arcgYearType arcgYearMonthType arcDateType"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="arcgYearType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:gYear">
        <xs:minInclusive value="1700"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="2100"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="arcgYearMonthType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:gYearMonth">
        <xs:minInclusive value="1700-01"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="2100-12"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="arcDateType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
        <xs:minInclusive value="1700-01-01"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="2100-12-31"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

When using xjc to compile them into javaclasses, i get the following exception:

```
[ERROR] 'y_ym_ymdDatoType' is already defined
 line 297 of file:../c.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
 line 309 of file:../a.xsd
```

and the same happens to the other elements: arcgYearType, arcgYearMonthType and arcDateType.

I have read about a binding file that maybe could solve this problem, but i am not sure on how to do it so examples will be highly preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve conflicts manually using binding file. Here is the example, where you can specify your custom name for conflicting names:

```
<bindings schemaLocation="../party.xsd" version="1.0" node="/xs:schema">
    <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='FixedIncomeBook']">
        <class name="PartyFixedIncomeBook"/>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Is this not acually renaming the XML elements when they come out, or is it just renaming the javaclasses that is generated?

Comment: It's renaming generated java class. By default you get `FixedIncomeBook.java` and with this binding you get `PartyFixedIncomeBook.java`

Comment: i get: [ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "". Perhaps you meant "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"?
  line 4 of file:/../C.xsd

The line #4 is schema definitions:

<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.sa.dk/xmlns/diark/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.sa.dk/xmlns/diark/1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" blockDefault="#all" finalDefault="extension restriction" version="0.9.4" id="contextDocumentationIndex" xml:lang="en">

Can you se what's wrong?

Comment: I solved the problem described above by giving all element a jxb: prefix on. But i still cannot get the original error to go away. So even though i still consider this answer as the right one, it hasn't solved my problem.

Comment: Sorry, @SofusAlbertsen, I forgot to specify namespace, you're right. As for the problem, I found that it's probably not related to JAXB, but in general because of wrong XSD set. Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714588/resolve-naming-conflict-in-included-xsds-for-jaxb-compilation

Comment: I went with compiling each of the XSD's into it's own package, just like the question you related to. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe, I assume that there is no include relationship between the XSD files. Also, I have to assume that you're trying to reuse classes, where content overlaps.

The easy way out is to "compile" each file independently, and provide a different Java package for each of the XSD files. The problem here is that if you try to "chain" together content from one XML to another (i.e. unmarshall from A and then marshall to B), then class C1 in package com.A, and class C1 in package com.B, while matching the same XSD complex type, are not "interchangeable"; you will have to develop a conversion between them. You need a custom binding file or if you use NetBeans, simply set different packages in the JAXB wizard.

The best way might be to use episodes (see [this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869547/jaxb-creating-modules-for-reuse)). Process A.xsd, then use that episode to process B.xsd, etc.

Comment: 1. No there is no include.
2. Yes i want to reuse, as they are the same, but that is not the primary goal, so if doing something else is easier then so be it.

I am not interested in something from A.xsd in C.xsd, i just use them all in the same project. Is there a straight forward way to make the packages defer even though their xsd's come from the same TNS?

Comment: @Sofus, then why are you not using episodes? Or run xjc against each package using a custom binding targetting different namespaces?

Comment: I went with compiling each of the XSD's into it's own package. Yet again, thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

A solution for the case when `A.xsd` contains common classes and is included into both `B.xsd` and `C.xsd`.

The solution has been tested with `maven-jaxb-plugin` version `3.1.0`.

You have to make 4 XJB files:

- `A.xjb` and `AClasses.xjb` for the common types from `A.xsd`
- `B.xjb` for the types specific to `B.xsd`
- `C.xjb` for the types specific to `C.xsd`

`A.xjb` will put the common types into the `common` Java package:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="https://targetnamespace">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="common"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

`AClasses.xjb` will instruct `B.xsd` and `C.xsd` to reuse the common types from the `common` Java package:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="https://targetnamespace">
    <bindings scd="~tns:CommonType1">
      <class ref="common.CommonType1"/>
    </bindings>
    <bindings scd="~tns:CommonType2">
      <class ref="common.CommonType2"/>
    </bindings>
    <!-- ... -->
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Note that `maven-jaxb-plugin` can generate most of the `AClasses.xjb` file for you, from execution on the `A.xsd`. Check out the `target/classes/META-INF/JAXB` directory after the execution.

`B.xjb` will put the `B.xsd` specific types into `package1`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="https://targetnamespace">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="package1"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

`C.xjb` will put the `C.xsd` specific types into `package2`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="https://targetnamespace">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="package2"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Finally, you have to define 3 `maven-jaxb-plugin` executions in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>

        <!-- Common configuration for all executions -->
        <configuration>
          <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>xjc-a</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>A.xsd</source>
              </sources>
              <xjbSources>
                <xjbSource>A.xjb</xjbSource>
              </xjbSources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>xjc-b</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>B.xsd</source>
              </sources>
              <xjbSources>
                <xjbSource>AClasses.xjb</xjbSource>
                <xjbSource>B.xjb</xjbSource>
              </xjbSources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>xjc-c</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>C.xsd</source>
              </sources>
              <xjbSources>
                <xjbSource>AClasses.xjb</xjbSource>
                <xjbSource>C.xjb</xjbSource>
              </xjbSources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```